# Custom UITableViewCells overlaps in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell:

[image]

But when tableView loads i've got overlaping cells in it:

[image]

I've tried to insert the following code into my `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But it does'not helps.

Comment: what constraints give to labels ?

Comment: can you show us the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method?

Comment: Are you tried return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat"

Comment: @TMob `if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? TasksTableViewCell {
            ..setting the cell labels..
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
`

Comment: @Che This don't helps

Comment: @Andrey M. please add the code to your question exactly as you have it in your program. Code-readability in comments isn't really good

Comment: Add bottom constrain for "Date:" label and height constraints for "Name", "Priority", "Date" labels. and replace 'tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight' with 'tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10' for example…

Comment: What is your custom tableViewCell height?

Comment: Now i just use UIStackView for labels and other stuff and it perfectly works! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
//Declaration
//SWIFT
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
//OBJECTIVE-C
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Make the method return the height of the cells. If this does not help, then you need to give us more details (and constraints probably).

EDIT:
I managed to fix the issue by doing 2 things:

1. Change those two lines:

   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150

   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

The tableview will automatically make the cells smaller

2. In the cell xib, you should add the constraint to the bottom of the cell. This way the height can be properly calculated.

If you want I can send you a working copy of the project, just give some contact mail or sth.

Comment: Added link to project

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight
```

Assuming that tableView is a UITableView, here you need to give a number, not the UITableView rowHeight property (something like 100).

Here you give an estimated height just to let the phone calculate the total height of the table, it is not the real height of each cell. So give the average heigh you estimate.

The `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is ok.

And also review the constraints in the cell view. To get this work you have to have constraints from the top to the bottom, and in the middle of the labels.

**Edit**: I've seen that the last constraint is missing (a bottom constraint for Date label)

Now, seeing the code, I'll say that this method is not neccesary:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok, you are missing 2 things: you need a bottom constraint in the last label (Date) and yo need to give a number to estimatedRowHeight (like 100)